# CSS make two divs in a column occupy the same height as an adjacent div

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to lay out a header for a page I'm working on.

The height of the header should be set from the main image in the center.  Beside this is a pair of divs one above the other, in y not z.  The lower of these two is a small image, the upper some text.  The small image will always be shorter than the main.

What I want is the bottom of both images to be aligned, leaving a space above the smaller one.  I then want the text div to automatically fill that space.

This is the best I've got so far.  Is there any way to make this do what I want?

```css
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     overflow-y: hidden;
     overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%
}

.outertable {
     display: table;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}

.headerrow {
     display: table-row;
     height: 0px;
     background-color: #ffff80
}

.fillimage {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: #80ff80
}

.pad40 {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 40px;
     background-color: #ff80ff
}

.widthofcontents {
     display: table-cell;
     width: 0px;
}

.columntable {
     display: flex;
     flex-flow: column;
}

.textfillavailable {
     font-size:25px;
     flex-grow: 1;
}

.heightofcontents {
     height: 0px;
}

.bodyrow {
     display: table-row;
     height: 100%;
}

.bodycontent {
}
```

```html
<div class="outertable">
  <div class="headerrow">
    <div class="fillimage">
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/120" />
    </div>

    <div class="pad40">
    </div>
    <div class="widthofcontents">
      <div class="columntable">
        <div class="textfillavailable">
          Hello
        </div>
        <div class="heightofcontents">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/90/70" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pad40">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyrow">
    <div class="bodycontent" contentEditable="true" />
  </div>
</div>
```

-- Edit --

Ascii art showing what I want

```
+-------------------------------+----------+
|                               |   Text   |
|        Large                  +----------+
|        Image                  |  Small   |
|                               |  Image   |
+-------------------------------+----------+
```

With the entire row having its height set to whatever the height of the large image is.

Comment: I'm sorry, your text description is super confusing. Can you make a drawing or something or supply an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @EGC I'd thought that running the snippet would have made it clear, but I've added some ASCII art to make it 100% clear.

Comment: That's some beautiful art

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use background images?

Answer (score 0):

my best guess.. but I'd say that your design might be very brittle...

https://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/1d48767a6d4b570924119e3dadc66bdf

```
<header>
    <section class="main">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/1600x900" alt="">
    </section>

    <section class="alternate">
        <section class="text">
            <p>Some text</p>
        </section>
        <section class="sub-image">
            <img src="https://placehold.it/800x450" alt="">
        </section>
    </section>
</header>
```

...

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
}

header {
    border: 1px solid red;
}

section {
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

header {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.alternate {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.alternate .text {
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save some markup and styling with a simple concept called [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). The code is explained in the comments. You can play around with this tool: [Grid Generator](https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/) if you need.

> With the entire row having its height set to whatever the height of
>   the large image is.

The two examples will let you know that the total layout height is dependent on the size of the bigger image which is what you need.

```css
.container {
  display: grid; /* Activate Grid Layout */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); /* Create two columns of a fraction each */
  grid-template-rows: minmax(min-content, max-content); /* Auto height rows according to content */
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  grid-row-gap: 5px; 
  margin: 15px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2; /* Start at Row 1, Start at Column 1, End at Row 3 1 and End at Column 2 */
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
}

/* Snippet styling */

.container > div {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></div>
  <div class="div2"> Some text </div>
  <div class="div3"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" /> </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="div1"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" /></div>
  <div class="div2"> Some text </div>
  <div class="div3"> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with this is that the columns and rows in the grid all have equal width and equal height.  In my example, the main pic is 120 px high, while the small is 70, meaning the text should be 50.  Likewise, there are the two 40 px pads on either side of the small pic, plus its own 90 px width, meaning the main image needs to pad itself to 100% minus 130 px.  The one thing I *DON'T* want to have to do is place the image dimensions in the HTML/CSS.  That makes the design brittle, because any alteration of the image sizes requires an HTML/CSS change.

Comment: I think I have a solution for you. Check the edit. `minmax(min-content, max-content)` is used.

Answer (score 0):

- Items in one row and with same height → `display: flex`.
- Set a width for the left and right side.
- Position image at the bottom of the right side `.right { position: relative; }` and `.right img { position: absolute; bottom: 0 }`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
}

.header img {
  display: block;
}

.header .left,
.header .right {
  border: 1px solid;
}

.header>.left {
  width: 70%;
}

.header>.left>img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.header>.right {
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.header>.right>.text {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
}

.header>.right>.text>* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.header>.right>img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  /* Center image horizontally */
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/250/120" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="text">
      <h5>Cat</h5>
      <p>Text tex text</p>
    </div>
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/90/70" />
  </div>
</div>
```